# Spring Batch Remote Partition Worker steps not starting parallel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch

We are trying to move from Local partition to remote partition. Issue we are facing is remote step partitions are not running parallel.

Below is the current code running parallel successful in local partition

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("masterStep")
public Step masterStep(final JpaRepositoryItemWriter<TutoPeople> writer) throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner()).step(workerStep(writer))
            .gridSize(8)).build();
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    //taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(threadQueuePoolSize);
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Below is the new code that not running in parallel but executing sequential.

### Manager Code - Master

```
   @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow() {
        final KafkaProducerMessageHandler kafkaMessageHandler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler(kafkaTemplate);
        kafkaMessageHandler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression("batchtopic"));
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(requests())
                .handle(kafkaMessageHandler)
                .get();
    }
   @Bean
    public DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    } 
   @Bean
    public ResourcePartitioner partitioner() throws IOException {
        return new ResourcePartitioner().setResources(getResources());
    }

    @Bean
    public Job partitionerJob(final BatchJobExecutionListener listener, final Step managerStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("partitionerJob")
                .listener(listener)
                .start(managerStep)
                .build();
    }
    
     @Bean
     public Step managerStep() throws Exception {
            return remoteStepBuilderFactory.get("managerStep")
                    .partitioner("workerStep", partitioner())
                    .gridSize(8)
                    .outputChannel(requests())
                    .inputChannel(replies())
                    .build();
        }

  private Resource[] getResources() throws IOException {
    final File inputDir = new FileSystemResource(this.dataPath).getFile();
    if (!inputDir.exists() || !inputDir.isDirectory())
        throw new IOException("Bad input configuration");

    return Arrays.stream(inputDir.listFiles()).map(FileSystemResource::new).toArray(FileSystemResource[]::new);
}
```

### Worker Code

```
@Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow() {
        final ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("batchtopic");
        final KafkaMessageListenerContainer container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer(kafkaFactory, containerProps);
        final KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter kafkaMessageChannel = new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(container);

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(kafkaMessageChannel)
                .channel(requests())
                .get();
    }

 @Bean
 @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<TutoPeople> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[filePath]}") String filePath) {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<TutoPeople>()
                .name("personReader")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath))
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<TutoPeople>() {{
                    setTargetType(TutoPeople.class);
                }})
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JpaRepositoryItemWriter<TutoPeople> writer(final TutoPeopleRepository repository) {
        return new JpaRepositoryItemWriter<>(repository);
    }

    @Bean
    public Step workerStep(final JpaRepositoryItemWriter<TutoPeople> writer) {
        return remoteStepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
                .inputChannel(requests())
                .outputChannel(replies())
                .startLimit(5)
                .<TutoPeople, TutoPeople>chunk(5)
                .reader(reader(null))
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting gridSize to 1? This should be >=2 unless it is ignored by your partitioner. You don't need a task executor on the `managerStep`. How is the inbound flow on the worker side configured? You did not share that. Are you sure messages are consumed concurrently from the `batchtopic`  on the worker side ?

Comment: Mahmoud- I have added the complete code of Master and worker. Gridsize we are overriding in partition as 8. Please note we are starting only 1 worker  as POC and assuming same worker will process all slaves(8) parallel in remote as I can see BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION is populated with 8 slave steps . Here Seems I am missing something . Each worker needs to process all slaves of same job id parallel from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION

Comment: Mahmoud- I started 8 workers and 2 started parallel even though I have 8 partitions. Is there any way I can assign to each kafka partition so that all worker gets data in parallel

Comment: Mahmoud - All the workers are starting parallel with RabitMQ but not happening for Kafka. Seems some config issue on Kafka

Comment: Indeed, you need to make sure that kafka consumers are concurrently reading step execution requests from the topic to start workers in parallel.

Comment: Mahmoud - Please let us know any code snippet or examples you have for Kafka .